# kerio vpn service high internet usage

Tags: networking, vpn

I use kerio vpn service to bypass governmental restrictions on the net. Recently I noticed an unusual internet usage, which is, given the high price of d/u traffic in our country, a real trouble. I carried out serveral download tests with and without vpn connection and the result is that the data transferred when kerio service is on, is *at least twice* as much as transferred when it's off.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the kerio vpn. If it is free and you installed client on your computer, then it might be a malware. But it is just a suspect. To find the detailed information about the unknown traffic, please perform a network capture on the server. I would suggest you to install the Network Monitor if your computer has Windows OS. It will tell you that what's the remote destination of the unknown traffic and which process initiates the connection.

Hope this helps.